# integration of the lorenz system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to integrate the system of differential equations of the lorenz attractor.But my problem is that when I take the initial conditions $x(0)=0,y(0)=0,z(0)=0$,using the rungekutta algorithm,I get solutions $x(t),y(t)$ and $z(t)$that are all equal to zero.Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at stationary or equilibrium points also the numerical methods give constant solutions. For stationary points the first equation gives $x=y$, the third gives $z\sim x^2$, and then the second equation fixes the values.

Comment: :thank you for replying,so should I change the initial conditions to get the Lorenz attractor   plot?

Comment: Yes. You could start close to the other stationary points (not too close) so that the plot starts with an outwards spiral. Or start otherwise, (1,1,1) or (8,8,8), or some positions replaced with zeros, seem popular points (no intrinsic significance).